# Django assign query object into array

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I assign query object into array? How do I assign test into test_list? So that I can assign it to use at template. **Can the template iterate the list?**

```
test_list = []

tests = Test.objects.all()

for test in tests:
   test_list.append(test)

return render_to_response('index.html', 
                         {'tests':test_list},)
```

The template:

```
{% for test in tests %}
    {{ test.name|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error:

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Test' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you show your model definition and entire view? From this snippet only it seems unreasonable that the iteration over "tests" fails.
How are you defining ".name"? is it a method or an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The question is why would you want to have the results of Test.objects.all in an "array"? (its called a [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) in python)

In your code, tests is a queryset object, that already supports most of an "array" operations, including slicing, etc.. etc.. Edit: That also means you can access and iterate them in the template. (django templates can iterate any "iterable" python object afaik.

Secondly, you probably should let the database do the querying, as it will do it more efficiently, using django queryset [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

test = Test.objects.all(quantity__gt=0)

If you still want a list, a nice way to create one is using a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

test_list = [test for test in Test.objects.all() if test.quantity > 0]

Comment: "if test.qunatity > 0:" is just an example, I want to assign the test object into list, so that it can be shown at template.

Comment: you do not need to assign it to a list, do the filtering in the database and pass it to render_to_response

Answer (score 0):

More of a Python question than Django one really, but use the append() function.

```
#don't use this one for your use case!
for test in tests:
  if test.quantity > 0:
     test_list.append(test)
```

Also, it would be more appropriate to do the filtering in the database

```
# get all items the quantity of which is greater than 0
tests = Test.objects.filter(quantity__gt=0)
```

your current code is not correct because:

```
tests = Test.objects.all()
for test in tests:
  # this statement is meaningless, it is always executed, you can just omit
  # this
  if True:
     #you are overwriting/-defining test_list variable
     #should be test_list.append(test)

     test_list = test
```

Comment: But when I render {'tests':test_list}, it shows me 'Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Test' object is not iterable' error.

Comment: Sorry all, "if test.qunatity > 0:" is just an example.

Comment: show us your template code, you are probably doing something wrong there.

Comment: I think the test in the list is not an object anymore.

Comment: please replace test_list=test with test_list.append(test) and it should be fine...

Comment: I have replace it to test_list.append(test).